# ACF dynamically set return type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

is there a way to dynamically set the return type of a field created by ACF ([advanced custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)).
So I am dynamically populating a dropdown options using the following:

```
add_action('acf/load_field/name=creature_select', function ($field): array {
    $field['choices'] = getCharacterOptions();

    return $field;
});
```

So for the same `creature_select` field it would be really useful to set the return type as an array programmatically instead of going through each instance of it in my ACF configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "set the return type"? Are you trying to avoid a PHPDOC message for the function return? Can you show more of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry - that was a bit confusing, I dont mean the function return type - I am referring to the ACF field return type. So for example with the Select field (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/) you can specify the return type be either, label, value or both